# Считается ли хорошим кодом определение get/set в абстрактном классе?

Tags: java, классы, get

У меня класс со свойствами, и там есть много геттеров и сеттеров. Мне нужно абстрагировать код, т.е. создать абстрактный класс(от которого естественно будет наследоваться обычный). Стоит ли указывать свойства и get/set в абстрактном классе?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

С точки зрения, если Ваша логика абстрактного класса будет использоваться в его наследниках, тогда стоит.
В принципе ничего плохого в этом нет, это же не интерфейс где такого быть не может.

Зачем лишний раз это делать в наследниках, если можно сделать один раз в абстрактном классе.